# Snowflake- How to populate value from array list based on case condition?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have below table tbl1 with day_val column

```
ID   Col1   Col2    Col3    col4    Col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10    day_val
101 null    b-col2  null    d-col4  null    null    f-col7  null    h-col9  g-col10  [  "3" ]
102 null    Null    c-col3  null    d-col5  e-col6  null    g-col8  null    null     [  "1",  "3" ]
103 a-col1  Null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null     [   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5"  ]
104 null    b-col2  null    d-col4  d-col5  null    null    null    null    null    [   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5" , "6", "7" ]
```

now i want to populate the days based on digit

```
now i want to create a column day based on number
col                                                                      day
[  "3" ]                                                                 Wednesday
[  "1",  "3" ]                                                          sunday, Wednesday
```

1 - represent sunday
2 - represent monday like that

i tried with below approach

```
SELECT tbl1.*,
  LISTAGG(day, ',') within group (order by val) AS days
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.seq,
    trim(t.value) as val,
    decode(val, '1','Sunday','2','Monday','3','Tuesday','4','Wednesday','5','Thursday','6','Friday','7','Saturday') as day
  FROM tbl1,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => col1) as t
)
GROUP BY seq
```

it returns with an error says 'tbl1' does not exist

#expected:
Respectively for each row

```
ID   Col1   Col2    Col3    col4    Col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10    day_val                                 Days
101 null    b-col2  null    d-col4  null    null    f-col7  null    h-col9  g-col10  [  "3" ]                                Tuesday
102 null    Null    c-col3  null    d-col5  e-col6  null    g-col8  null    null     [  "1",  "3" ]                          Monday, Tuesday
103 a-col1  Null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null     [   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5"  ]         Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednsday, Thursday
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you swap from FLATTENing the SPLIT to just flatten the array:

```
with day_val(col1) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
        ('[  "3" ]'),
        ('[  "1",  "3" ]'),
        ('[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5"  ]'),
        ('[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5" , "6", "7" ]')
)
--SELECT
--  col1,
--  LISTAGG(day, ',') AS days
--FROM (
  SELECT
    t.seq,
    trim(t.value),
    CASE trim(t.value)
      WHEN '1' THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN '2' THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN '3' THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN '5' THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN '6' THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN '7' THEN 'Saturday'
      ELSE NULL
    END AS day
  FROM day_val,
  --LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => SPLIT(col1, ',')) AS t
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => col1) as t
--)
--GROUP BY col1;
```

you can see the CASE token makes more sense:

[image]

and then you can also use a decode if you want it be more compact. Also you would want to avoid carry the original array (as it a lot of data) and use the SEQuence of the flatten to correctly identify rows.

You should also problay order the LIST, because as it stand it can be randomly arrange if the optimizer likes:

```
with day_val(col1) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
        ('[  "3" ]'),
        ('[  "1",  "3" ]'),
        ('[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5"  ]'),
        ('[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5" , "6", "7" ]')
)
SELECT
  LISTAGG(day, ',') within group (order by val) AS days
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.seq,
    trim(t.value) as val,
    CASE trim(t.value)
      WHEN '1' THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN '2' THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN '3' THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN '5' THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN '6' THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN '7' THEN 'Saturday'
      ELSE NULL
    END AS day
  FROM day_val,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => col1) as t
)
GROUP BY seq;
```

| DAYS |
| --- |
| Sunday,Tuesday |
| Tuesday |
| Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday |
| Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday |

the decode version (without the data CTE):

```
SELECT
  LISTAGG(day, ',') within group (order by val) AS days
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.seq,
    trim(t.value) as val,
    decode(val, '1','Sunday','2','Monday','3','Tuesday','4','Wednesday','5','Thursday','6','Friday','7','Saturday') as day
  FROM day_val,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => col1) as t
)
GROUP BY seq;
```

### Scope Creep:

```
with data(ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, col4, Col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, day_val) as (
    SELECT * from VALUES
    (101, null     ,'b-col2' ,null     ,'d-col4'  ,null      ,null      ,'f-col7'  ,null      ,'h-col9'  ,'g-col10'  ,'[  "3" ]'),
    (102, null     ,Null     ,'c-col3' ,null      ,'d-col5'  ,'e-col6'  ,null      ,'g-col8'  ,null      ,null       ,'[  "1",  "3" ]'),
    (103, 'a-col1' ,Null     ,null     ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null       ,'[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5"  ]'),
    (104, null     ,'b-col2' ,null     ,'d-col4'  ,'d-col5'  ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null      ,null       ,'[   "1",  "2", "3", "4", "5" , "6", "7" ]')
)
SELECT
    * exclude(seq,val,day),
  LISTAGG(day, ',') within group (order by val) AS days
FROM (
  SELECT
    d.* exclude(day_val),
    t.seq,
    trim(t.value) as val,
    decode(val, '1','Sunday','2','Monday','3','Tuesday','4','Wednesday','5','Thursday','6','Friday','7','Saturday') as day
  FROM data as d,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => PARSE_JSON(d.day_val)) as t
)
GROUP BY ALL;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Simon.. However i need all other columns to populated in the decode version code

Comment: @Simon, the days returning the result.. But i need to populate ID as well in the returning result

Comment: One or many extra columns is trivial, just select them. And add then to the group by.

Comment: i have updated questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
create or replace temporary table t (id int, day_nums variant) as

select 101, ['3'] union all
select 102, ['1','5'] union all
select 103, ['4','6','7'] union all
select 104, ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
```

---

```
select id, 
       day_nums,
       array_agg(get(['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat'],value::int-1))  within group (order by value) as day_names
from t, 
lateral flatten(day_nums) --assuming what you have is an array
group by id, day_nums;
```

Comment: Hi @Kathmandude,  i have updated question. i want other column to be populated

Comment: @Hari Just include those columns in the `group by`. See my update

Comment: got it.. i have one more question what if i have 10 columns in the table, and i cannot add all columns in to the group by clause. Other than id we have 9 more columns

Comment: @Hari That's why it's important to include a representative problem/sample in the question. That said, just build a temp using that query and then join it back to your original dataset.

Comment: For the too many GROUP BY there is a parameter ALL and snowflake will work out the needed eet for you.